# Delete all files with an extension using Java

Tags: java, file

I'm (relatively) new to Java and I'm trying to implement a .jar that runs a list of commands that in Windows XP's command prompt it would be:

```
cd\
cd myfolder
del *.lck /s
```

My (failed) attempt:

```
// Lists all files in folder
File folder = new File(dir);
File fList[] = folder.listFiles();
// Searchs .lck
for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
    String pes = fList.get(i);
    if (pes.contains(".lck") == true) {
        // and deletes
        boolean success = (new File(fList.get(i)).delete());
    }
}
```

I screwed somewhere around that "get(i)", but I think I'm pretty close to my goal now.

I ask for your help and thank you very much in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Alright! Many thanks, everybody. With the 3 suggested modifications I ended up with:

```
// Lists all files in folder
File folder = new File(dir);
File fList[] = folder.listFiles();
// Searchs .lck
for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
    String pes = fList[i];
    if (pes.endsWith(".lck")) {
        // and deletes
        boolean success = (new File(fList[i]).delete());
    }
}
```

And now it works!

2022 version:

```java
public static boolean deleteAllFilesWithSpecificExtension(String pathToDir, String extension) {
        boolean success = false;
        File folder = new File(pathToDir);
        File[] fList = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList) {
            String pes = file.getName();
            if (pes.endsWith("." + extension)) {
                success = (new File(String.valueOf(file)).delete());
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: There's no `get` method of an array, meaning `fList.get(i)` won't compile.  Instead, to access object `i` in an array, do `fList[i]`.

Comment: could be better change pes.contains(".lck") with pes.endsWith(".lck")

Comment: You should also use [`endsWith(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) instead of [`contains(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)), unless you want things like *myfile.lck.exe* to be deleted as well.

Comment: Thanks. Just the nearer a suggestion to those three lines of commands I wrote, the better~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fList.get(i)` should be `fList[i]` as `fList` is an array, and it returns a `File` reference not a `String`.

Change: -

```
String pes = fList.get(i);
```

to: -

```
File pes = fList[i];
```

And then change `if (pes.contains(".lck") == true)` to 
`if (pes.getName().contains(".lck"))`

In fact, since you are checking for the `extension`, you should use `endsWith` method rather than `contains` method. And yes, you don't need to compare your `boolean` value with `==`. So just use this condition: -

```
if (pes.getName().endsWith(".lck")) {
    boolean success = (new File(fList.get(i)).delete());
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (f.getName().endsWith(".lck")) {
        f.delete(); // may fail mysteriously - returns boolean you may want to check
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 approach

```
Arrays.stream(yourDir.listFiles((f, p) -> p.endsWith("YOUR_FILE_EXTENSION"))).forEach(File::delete);
```

Answer (score 3):

Final Code which works :)

```
File folder = new File(dir);
                File fList[] = folder.listFiles();

                for (File f : fList) {
                    if (f.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
                        f.delete(); 
                    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Collection` method `get` on an `Array`. Use `Array Index` notation as below:

```
        File pes = fList[i];
```

Also better to use [**endsWith()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29)  String method over the file name as:

```
   if (pes.getName().endsWith(".lck")){
      ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 lambda

```
File folder = new File(yourDirString);
Arrays.stream(folder.listFiles())
            .filter(f -> f.getName().endsWith(".lck"))
            .forEach(File::delete);
```

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation to your answer, why does your code snippet help the OP with their question?