# How Can I remove an APK file using the package name?

Tags: android

Consider we have an `APK` file in an internal storage or external storage.How Can I remove an `APK` file using the package name and not with the file name? Is this possible in android?

Comment: do you mean a non installed apk file? and how you suppose to read the package address from it? delete the file by name... search all the *.apk file and delete them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663843/delete-all-files-with-an-extension-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Check this info from documentation:

[image]

You can use this method to get PackageInfo from your apk file then you could verify package name to do what you want.

Hope that it helps.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)